# Python non-linear optimization problem (minimize) in SciPy

Tags: optimization, minimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to solve a shift scheduling optimisation problem in Python that is slightly different from the one outlined in this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-solve-a-staff-scheduling-problem-with-python-63ae50435ba4). The only issue is I can't use the `pulp` package as it is not a linear problem.

From what I understand, the best way to solve my problem is to use the `scipy.optimize` package, however I am having difficulties translating the following [problem formulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT76E.jpg) into actual code. The inputs are straightforward (two arrays) and the goal is to minimize a function with a constraint.

**Problem formulation**

- Dimensions: `i=1...T` (hours of the day), `j=1...n` (total number of multi-hour shifts for the day)
- Inputs: `a[i,j]` (two-dimensional array storing the shift configuration) and `d[i]` (expected demand for the hour `i`)
- Output: the script must return the optimal number of workers required for each shift `w[j]`
- Minimization: we want to minimize the total cost of workers for the day. What makes the problem slightly more complicated is the cost per hour `c[i]` is a function of `w[j]` (we don't pay the same hourly wage if there are too many workers): `min(sum c[i])` (i=1...T) where `c[i] = d[i]^2 / sum(a[i,j]*w[j])` (j=1...n).
- Constraint: for all i, `sum a[i,j] w[j] >= d[i]` (to ensure workers can meet the level of demand for each hour)

**Code**

```
w = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("num_workers", list(range(n)), lowBound=0, cat="Integer")
pulp.lpSum([(d[i]^2 / pulp.lpSum([a[i,j] * w[j] for j in range(n)])) for i in range(T)])
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'LpAffineExpression'

Could anyone give me some hints on how to turn the following problem into an actual code understandable by SciPi? Thanks!

Comment: Even extremely complicated scheduling problems can be expressed in a linear model, sometimes with a lot of additional variables.  This is almost certainly preferable (and more solvable) than going non-linear with `scipy`.  What characteristic makes your scheduling non-linear?

Comment: Thanks @AirSquid. When using ```pulp```, I got an error when defining the sum to be minimised:
`pulp.lpSum([(d[i]^2 / pulp.lpSum([a[i,j] * w[j] for j in range(n)])) for i in range(T)])`
Error is: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'LpAffineExpression' - this made me think divisions are not supported with linear programming.

Comment: Can you edit your orig post above and include this section of code, along with the sections that define `d, a, w`.  Also include (in plain english) what you want from that objective function.  There is likely a way to do what you want, but there isn't enough info in your comment

Comment: Thanks! I added more information about the problem, and the beginning of the code I ran. Hope this helps! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as it was suggested in the comments, one can approximate most of non-linear constraints and objectives by using piecewise linearization. It significantly reduces computational complexity of your problem.

However, for non-linear optimization in Python you may consider using [pyomo](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) optimization package, which fully supports open-source non-linear solvers ([ipopt](https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/) for continuous problems, [couenne](https://projects.coin-or.org/Couenne) for non-convex mixed-integer non-linear programming or [bonmin](https://projects.coin-or.org/Bonmin) for convex mixed-integer nonlinear programming

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an issue w/ your formulation....

First, a typo:  in `python` exponentiation is double asterisk, so this is proper (you just popped a different error before this one hit):

```
d[i]**2
```

Second, I think you have a problem with your cost function `c[i]`.  As it is written above, your costs go down the more workers you hire, which is nonsensical.  If you hired a million workers in time period `i`, then the cost would be infinitesimally small.

I would suggest you take a hard look at the relationships of cost and **wage**.  And in the process relabel some things to make this read easier:

```
x:  Number of workers to hire
w:  Wage (indexed by either shift or hour, doesn't matter)
c:  Cost (indexed by wage or hour)
```

hand-jam a couple of example numbers into these formula to ensure you get something believable out of them.

Comment back if I've mis-interpreted this...